# Changing Mosaic Dataset Properties in Map Document using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, mosaic-dataset

Does anyone know if it is possible in ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop to access and change mosaic dataset properties within a map document using ArcPy?

I am trying to write text into the symbology description in the boundary layer of a mosaic dataset (not the description field on the layer properties general tab of the mosaic dataset).

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [Describe](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Mosaic_Dataset_properties/018v0000001z000000/) method on a mosaic dataset then all it's properties are read only.

If you get a handle on the Mosaic dataset as a layer object then according to [Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Layer/00s300000008000000/) if the SymbologyType property returns OTHER then the layers symbology cannot be altered.

The following code returned OTHER for a mosaic dataset I have so I guess you cannot change it?

```py
import arcpy
ml = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"G:\GIS\fGDB_GHSL_Agg_300m.gdb\mosGHSL1990_300mAgg")
print ml.symbologyType #Returns OTHER
```